# How do "while" statements affect the execution of RinSim?

Tags: java, rinsim

I have some `while` statements in my project, specifically of the type:

```
while(!rm.getPosition(this).equals(destination.get())) {
    rm.moveTo(this, destination.get(), time);
}
```

Additionally, I have some `while`'s to make an agent wait for a message.

My question is, will these `while`'s only affect the behavior of my agent, or, on the other hand, will this delay the execution of the rest of my agents? I.e., will the entire program wait until my while is completed?

I'm using version 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet in your code may result in an infinite loop. I'm assuming that your code resides somewhere in a `tick(..)` method, like this:

```
@Override
public void tick(TimeLapse timeLapse) {
  while(!rm.getPosition(this).equals(destination.get())) {
    rm.moveTo(this, destination.get(), timeLapse);
  }
}
```

Upon entering this method, the [TimeLapse](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.rinde/rinsim-core/4.1.1/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/time/TimeLapse.html) object will contain unconsumed time. The first time [RoadModel#moveTo(..)](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.rinde/rinsim-core/4.1.1/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/road/RoadModel.html#moveTo-com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.MovingRoadUser-com.github.rinde.rinsim.geom.Point-com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.TimeLapse-) is called, the `RoadModel` will try to move the object `this` closer towards the specified destination using all travel time available in `timeLapse`. Two possibilities:

1. In case the distance to the destination is small enough to travel it within the available time (depending on the speed of the object), the destination will be reached, and the program will exit the loop. The `moveTo(..)` method will only consume the amount of time it needs, leaving any unneeded time unconsumed in the `timeLapse` object.
2. Alternatively, in case the destination is further away than can be traveled within the available time in `timeLapse`, the `timeLapse` will be depleted and the vehicle will not reach it's destination (but it does get closer). This causes the loop to never exit, any subsequent calls to `moveTo(..)` are ignored by the `RoadModel` because the `timeLapse` is empty.

So yes, using this code will affect your entire program and will likely result in an infinite loop. The correct approach is to replace the `while` with an `if`. You can then add an `else` clause to perform an auction when the destination is reached.

Comment: Thank you Rinde! Yes, I kind of figure it out the hard way haha.